# Access list of view modes available for nodes

Tags: 8, entities

In my code, I need to get a list of all the view modes defined for nodes.

In Drupal 7, it was available via `entity_get_info()`. What is the equivalent method for producing a list of available view modes in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View modes are config entities, so an entity query would do the trick:

```
$view_modes = Drupal::entityQuery('entity_view_mode')
  ->condition('targetEntityType', 'node')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: It is no (longer ?) entity_view_mode but entity_view_display.
You can also specificate the bundles with 
->condition('bundle', ['full', 'teaser']

Comment: @PierreNoel It's still `entity_view_mode` to get view modes... `entity_view_display` is something different (when you want to get the settings for how fields are displayed within a particular view mode)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `entity_display.repository` service (`EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface`).

```
// Getting all display modes configured for nodes.
\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewModeOptions('node')

// Getting all display modes configured for nodes with content type article
\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')
    ->getViewModeOptionsByBundle('node', 'article')
```