# Get labels of view modes in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, nodes, configuration

I'm trying to rebuild the [pullquote](https://www.drupal.org/project/pullquote) module in Drupal 8 but am running into an issue accessing view modes. In the Drupal 7 version, the view_modes variable is set by the following lines:

```
$entity_info = entity_get_info('node');
$view_modes = $entity_info['view modes'];
$view_mode_options = array();

foreach ($view_modes as $mode => $settings) {
  $view_mode_options[$mode] = $settings['label'];
}
```

However, `entity_get_info()` has been depreciated in Drupal 8, and according to [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1929006) I found, replaced with `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition()`.

So I tried replacing the first line:

```
$nodeEntity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node');
```

but the array was empty, so maybe I'm using the wrong tool.

I then found [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205575/access-list-of-view-modes-available-for-nodes) for accessing a list of all view nodes.

```
$view_modes = \Drupal::entityQuery('entity_view_mode')
  ->condition('targetEntityType', 'node')
  ->execute();
```

It worked, however, they were returned like this:

```
['node.full', 'node.rss', 'node.teaser']
```

But here's the problem. I'm using these view modes as options in a form. When the form is saved in configuration, having a key with a period breaks the YAML file with the following error: `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigValueException: node.full key contains a dot which is not supported. in Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigBase->validateKeys()`. I'm confused though, because I map over the array so that I'm stripping the names of ".node"

Here's my full code for reference:

```
// Load the list of avialable view modes.
$view_modes = \Drupal::entityQuery('entity_view_mode')
  ->condition('targetEntityType', 'node')
  ->execute();

// remove "node."
$view_mode_options = array_map(function ($mode) {
  $parsed = substr($mode, 5);
  return $parsed;
}, $view_modes);

$form['view_mode_settings']['pullquote_view_modes'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('View Modes'),
  '#options' => $view_mode_options,
  '#default_value' => $config->get('pullquote_view_modes'),
  '#description' => t('Choose which view modes will load pullquote code and render pullquotes. For better performance you should only load pullquote where you need it.'),
   '#states' => array(
     'visible' => array(
       ':input[name="pullquote_load_by_view_mode"]' => array('value' => 1),
       ':input[name="pullquote_scope"]' => array('value' => 0),
     ),
   ),
];
```

Now the view modes display properly on the page, but I still get the error that Drupal can't save "node.full" in configuration, which is confusing because the page displays only "full."

Is there a method for getting the label of different entity types? Or is there a way to actually parse "node.full" down to a string that is only "full"--both when it displays and how Drupal understands it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal 8 services are essentially helpful objects (tools), which live inside the services container (tool belt). Calling a service returns an object, essentially providing a clear path to the helper methods within that class. As previously answered, `EntityDisplayRepository` class contains various methods, specifically one that will return an array of entity view modes ([see a list of available methods](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityDisplayRepository.php/class/EntityDisplayRepository/8.5.x)). By calling `\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')` and storing it in a variable, you now have an object that you can then call `EntityDisplayRepository` methods from, which in your case, is to return 'node' view modes.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 *
 * This function is called before the page is rendered.
 */
function modulename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // call the entity service.
  $nodeEntity = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');

  // call the necessary method in order to return 'node' view modes.
  $nodeEntity->getViewModes('node');

  // one line: \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewModes('node');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository::getViewModeOptions()` aka  the service `\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')`, that gives you an array with the label.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit in how to use this? I tried `$view_modes = \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository::getViewModeOptions('node');` and got the error "Error: Using $this when not in object context in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepository::getViewModeOptions() (line 154 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityDisplayRepository.php)"

Comment: You need to call that on the service, not the class.

Comment: Can you give an example? What is the service? What is the class?

Comment: `\Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewModes('node')` but better use the DI service instead if possiible.